# Can a Bard trade in two spells with magical secrets when he gains a level?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, class-feature

When a lore bard  gets to 6th level, can he trade in two spell instead of one, when he picks his two spells with his magical secrets feature?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## The Magical Secrets feature does not trade in spells

> The chosen spells count as bard spells for you and are included in the number in the Spells Known column of the Bard table.

These do not replace your bard spells but are added to the same; the same is true for the spells gained at 14th and 18th; they are added to the Spells Known.

When you reach 10th level, you do get the opportunity to exchange one bard spell with another from the bard spell list (of a level you can cast), just like any other level, but this is unconnected to Magical Secrets (Although you could replace your Magical Secrets spells on level up.in this way; thanks V2Blast).

> ...when you gain a level in this class, you can choose one of the bard spells you know and replace it with another spell from the bard spell list, which also must be of a level for which you have spell slots.